# Convert ABAP data into an iXML object representing them in JSON-XML format

Tags: json, xml, transformation, abap

I want to read arbitrary ABAP data into an [`iXML`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenabap_ixml_lib.htm) document object which contains the [`JSON-XML`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenabap_json_xml.htm) representation of these data.

The only way I see is a double application of the `id` transformation which is not very efficient:

```
data(lo_aux1) = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( if_sxml=>co_xt_json ).
call transformation id
  source data = ls_some_abap_data
  result xml lo_aux1.
data(lv_aux2) = lo_aux1->get_output( ).
data(lo_result) = cl_ixml=>create( )->create_document( ).
call transformation id
  source xml lv_aux2
  result xml lo_result.
```

Now `lo_result` is an `iXML` DOM representation of the ABAP data in the `JSON-XML` format, as required. Is it possible to obtain it in a more direct way?

Note: I am *not interested in result objects of the `sXML` family*, as I want to manipulate / extend the resulting `JSON-XML` document with the usual XML DOM methods, which is impossible for an `sXML` writer object (`sXML` writers are so simple they can only write everything they have into an output object, but don't allow editing of parts of the object that they already contain).

Comment: Not that I know. Candid question, but why do you need `JSON-XML` rather than `asXML` format? (I think it's not so required if you use the `iXML` library)

Comment: The scenario is: I am sitting at a proxy and want to enrich the incoming JSON payload by some ABAP data, before passing it to the endpoint. Strategy: parse the incoming JSON into an JSON-XML doc, read the (complex) ABAP data into a second XML doc, then add XML subtrees of the second to the first before finally producing the result JSON from the first JSON-XML doc.

Answer (score 1):

> I am sitting at a proxy and want to enrich the incoming JSON payload by some ABAP data, before passing it to the endpoint. Strategy: parse the incoming JSON into an JSON-XML doc, read the (complex) ABAP data into a second XML doc, then add XML subtrees of the second to the first before finally producing the result JSON from the first JSON-XML doc

I don't understand the need of iXML at all here. Converting complex ABAP structure into XML to merge it with JSON is redundant here. Let's assume you received some JSON data from Web-Service:

```
{  
   "main":{  
      "PASSENGERS":[  
         {  
            "NAME":"Horst",
            "TITLE":"Herr",
            "AGE":30
         },
         {  
            "NAME":"Jutta",
            "TITLE":"Frau",
            "AGE":35
         },
         {  
            "NAME":"Ingo",
            "TITLE":"Herr",
            "AGE":31
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And you want enrich each passenger data with flight data from `SFLIGHT` table. You can manipulate the nodes and attributes with `cl_sxml_string_writer` just like this:

```
DATA(lv_json) = CONV string( '{"main": {"PASSENGERS":[ {"NAME":"Horst","TITLE":"Herr","AGE":30}, {"NAME":"Jutta","TITLE":"Frau","AGE":35}, {"NAME":"Ingo","TITLE":"Herr","AGE":31} ]}}' ).

DATA open_element TYPE REF TO if_sxml_open_element.
DATA value TYPE REF TO if_sxml_value_node.

DATA(o_json) = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to( lv_json ).
DATA(reader) = cl_sxml_string_reader=>create( o_json ).

SELECT DISTINCT connid, fldate, planetype FROM sflight INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_flight).

DATA(xml) = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to( lv_json ).

DATA(out) = cl_demo_output=>new( )->begin_section( 'Original JSON' )->write_xml( xml ).

DATA(writer) = CAST if_sxml_writer( cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( ) ).
open_element = writer->new_open_element( name = 'flights' nsuri = reader->nsuri ).
writer->write_node( open_element ).
DATA(i) = 1.
DO.
  DATA(node) = reader->read_next_node( ).
  IF node IS INITIAL.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.
  IF node IS INSTANCE OF if_sxml_value_node.
    DATA(value_node) = CAST if_sxml_value_node( node ).
    value_node->set_value( to_upper( value_node->get_value( ) ) ).
  ENDIF.
  writer->write_node( node ).
  IF node->type = if_sxml_node=>co_nt_element_open.
    DATA(op) = CAST if_sxml_open_element( node ).
    CHECK op->qname-name = 'object' AND op->get_attributes( ) IS INITIAL.
    open_element = writer->new_open_element( name = 'flight' nsuri = reader->nsuri ).
    open_element->set_attribute( name = 'FLIGHT_DATE'
                                 value = | { lt_flight[ i ]-fldate } | ).
    open_element->set_attribute( name = 'PLANE_TYPE'
                                 value = | { lt_flight[ i ]-planetype } | ).
    writer->write_node( open_element ).
    value = writer->new_value( ).
    value->set_value( | { lt_flight[ i ]-connid } | ).
    writer->write_node( value ).
    writer->write_node( writer->new_close_element( ) ).
    i = i + 1.
  ENDIF.
ENDDO.
writer->write_node( writer->new_close_element( ) ).
out->next_section( 'Modified JSON'
  )->write_xml(
    CAST cl_sxml_string_writer( writer )->get_output( )
  )->display( ).

DATA(result_json) = CAST cl_sxml_string_writer( writer )->get_output(  ).
```

Resulted JSON will be dumped into `result_json` variable and you can push it further wherever you want.

Here is resulted JSON, with capitalized passenger values and extended with `flight` node, which contains flight number and attributed with data and plane type:

```
<flights>
 <object>
  <flight FLIGHT_DATE=" 20160610 " PLANE_TYPE=" A380‑800 "> 0002 </flight>
  <object name="main">
   <array name="PASSENGERS">
    <object>
     <flight FLIGHT_DATE=" 20160712 " PLANE_TYPE=" A380‑800 "> 0002 </flight>
     <str name="NAME">HORST</str>
     <str name="TITLE">HERR</str>
     <num name="AGE">30</num>
    </object>
    <object>
     <flight FLIGHT_DATE=" 20160813 " PLANE_TYPE=" A380‑800 "> 0002 </flight>
     <str name="NAME">JUTTA</str>
     <str name="TITLE">FRAU</str>
     <num name="AGE">35</num>
    </object>
    <object>
     <flight FLIGHT_DATE=" 20160914 " PLANE_TYPE=" A380‑800 "> 0002 </flight>
     <str name="NAME">INGO</str>
     <str name="TITLE">HERR</str>
     <num name="AGE">31</num>
    </object>
   </array>
  </object>
 </object>
</flights>
```

Comment: Good point: instead of trying to edit the incoming XML in-place, you suggest to change that viewpoint: to build a new XML document instead, feeding it from both sources, Viable, but doesn't answer the question itself, which was for a transformation of ABAP data into an XML document containing the data in JSON-XML format (the best would be a built-in transformation like ABAP2JSON, provided by the basis, but as such a thing doesn't exist...).

Comment: I always try to solve real-life problems instead of solving synthetic theoretical tasks, and your question is purely synthetic. I am not building XML from scratch, but rather read source JSON and add lacking nodes from ABAP thus avoiding creating additional objects which consume memory

Comment: Your `writer` refers to a newly created XML document, and you fill it from scratch by copying parts of two inputs (namely those contained in the variables `reader` and `lt_flight`), instead of editing the given XML. Also, I didn't ask how useful or practical you find my question, but I asked for an answer.